# Make a function that can perform multiple callback with one parameter

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm working on a big project and I simplified what it matters here. This is the code:

```js
a = new Thing(/*sayHi + sayHey*/);

function sayHi() {
    alert("hi");
}

function sayHey() {
    alert("hey");
}

function Thing (callback) {
    callback();
}
```

I'd like to, with just the `callback` parameter, call both the `sayHi()` and the `sayHey()` function, at the order I put them. Is it possible? How would I do it? Thank you.

Comment: I'm confused, why not just pass them, like so -> http://jsfiddle.net/bvqfnw4p/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass an anonymous function that calls both of them sequentially:

```js
a = new Thing(function() {
    sayHi();
    sayHey();
});

function sayHi() {
    alert("hi");
}

function sayHey() {
    alert("hey");
}

function Thing (callback) {
    callback();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to @Barnar's answer, create and pass a regular named function. If the callback logic gets heavier, you might want that anyway.

```
function hiHeyCallback() {
    sayHi();
    sayHey();
}

a = new Thing(hiHeyCallback);
```

Comment: I think that in my case I might want @Barnar's answer, but thank you anyway!